# Array not working with the modulo operator

Tags: ruby, arrays

The first code works, but I don't understand why the second one doesn't. Any insight would be appreciated. I know in this example I really don't need an array, I just wanted to get it to work for the sake of learning.

```
def stamps(input)
  if input % 5 == 0
    puts 'Zero!'
  else
    puts 'NO!'
  end
end

print stamps(8)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
array_of_numbers = [8]

def stamps(input_array)
  if input_array % 5 == 0
    puts 'Zero!'
  else
    puts 'NO!'
  end
end

print stamps(array_of_numbers)
```

Comment: There is no `%` method defined for arrays. How do you expect your second example to work?

Comment: Well, what did you expect the code in your second example to do? What if there was both an 8 *and* a 5 in the array? What would you expect your code to do then?

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, thank you guys for showing me the error of my way, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because input_array is an array and 8 is a number. Use `first` to retrieve the first element of the array.

```
array_of_numbers = [8]

def stamps(input_array)
  if input_array.first % 5 == 0
    puts 'Zero!'
  else
    puts 'NO!'
  end
end

print stamps(array_of_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function works in case the input is number or array:

```
def stamps(input)
  input = [input] unless input.is_a?(Array)
  if input.first % 5 == 0
    puts 'Zero!'
  else
    puts 'NO!'
  end
end
```